# Iterate through array of object and check if it has given property or not using typescript or javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my angular 6 application, I have below json object which is being retrieved from Backend.

```
"participants": [{
        "dateJoin": 1520409578,
        "dateLeft": 0,
        "firstName": "edh",
        "internalId": 165,
        "invitedBy": "edh",
        "lastName": "edh",
        "userId": "edh",
        "key":"data"

    }, {
        "dateJoin": 1520409578,
        "dateLeft": 0,
        "firstName": "",
        "internalId": 166,
        "invitedBy": "edh",
        "lastName": "",
        "userId": "ATB"
    }],
    "dataInAB": "ATB",
    "subject": "test ",
    "unreadMessageCount": 0,
    "updateDate": 1520585258,
    "updatedBy": "atb"
}
```

In above array of object I would like to know if it does have property called key or not ? if not it will check for another object and check for it using typescript. the place for key can exist in any object of participants. If it exists anywhere return value of it.

I know using hasOwnProperty but I am not sure if it will iterate through all the object or not ?
Thanks

Comment: `participants` is an array, so you could loop over each element an check if that element has the property. Like: `participants.forEach(obj => { if(obj.hasOwnProperty("key")) { // do something } })`

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

if you want check whether array has object with `key` property, then use `some` method. If you want to get all objects in array which has `key` property, then use `filter` method:

```js
const arr = [{
    "dateJoin": 1520409578,
    "dateLeft": 0,
    "firstName": "edh",
    "internalId": 165,
    "invitedBy": "edh",
    "lastName": "edh",
    "userId": "edh",
    "key": "data"

}, 
{
    "dateJoin": 1520409578,
    "dateLeft": 0,
    "firstName": "",
    "internalId": 166,
    "invitedBy": "edh",
    "lastName": "",
    "userId": "ATB"
}];

const hasKey= arr.some(s => s.key);
console.log(`hasKey: ${hasKey}`);
const objectsWithKeyProperties = arr.filter(f => f.key);
console.log(`objectsWithKeyProperties :`, objectsWithKeyProperties);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to retrieve all elements from an array that match your filter.

The function accepts a callback function as argument that has to return `true` to keep the element or `false` to drop the element. The function than returns a new array containing all elements matching the filter:

```js
const result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].filter((num) => num > 3);
// result will look like this: [4, 5]
```

For your problem, you would check if the required property is `undefined`:

```js
participants.filter((participant) => participant.key !== undefined);
```

This function will return a new array, containing all objects that have a property named *key*.

We can make it event shorter using some Javascript magic and omitting the `!== undefined` check because in an `if` condition, `undefined` equals false and any other result (except boolean `false`) equals `true`:

```js
participants.filter((participant) => participant.key);
```

**Snippet:**

```js
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].filter((num) => num > 3));

const participants = [
  {name: "John", key: "zero"},
  {name: "Prince"}
];

console.log(participants.filter((participant) => participant.key));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rfmce9?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

```
getValueOfKey() {
    for (var obj of this.data.participants) {
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty('key')){
         return obj.key;
      }
    }
}
```